# Как происходит сортировка, поиск, выборка, или как делают функционал сортировки поиска, выборки. Интернет магазин

Tags: javascript, ajax, запрос, get, клиент-сервер

Правильно ли я понимаю что в большинстве случаях сортировку, выборку или поиск делают путем AJAX, то есть путем GET запроса передавая нужные параметры? Имеется в виду Интернет магазин

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно сами методы сортировки и прочего делаются на сервере. Потому что там база данных и бизнес-логика. А на клиент выставляют только API, в котором могут быть методы сортировки и прочего или не быть.

Тип запроса может быть разный, например ajax post, или обычная отправка формы с перезагрузкой страницы. Если нужно на фоне запрос отправить и крутить анимацию загрузки, то соответственно ajax. Если поле ввода и нужна новая страница результатов, то через отправку формы.

POST или GET выбирается соответственно их особенностям. Если нужно кеширование и чтобы все видели параметры запроса или могли их где-то сохранить в закладки, то GET. Если кеширование не нужно или важно скрывать параметры, то POST. Это я упрощённо.